# Base de donnée / corpus pour analyse de sentiments

Tags: ressources, comparatifs, linguistique, apprentissage

J'espère ne pas être trop hors sujet pour ce stack exchange.

Je cherche à faire de l'analyse de sentiments de tweets, et pour ça, je cherche une base de donnée de mots en français, avec :

- soit un indice de positivité/négativité/neutralité,
- soit quelque chose les affiliant à un ou des sentiments ?

Merci par avance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure - do you want a dataset with labels to train a ML system? Maybe you can find something with Google - they have really good n-grams dataset, for example. I know that is not related to sentiment analysis, but maybe they have something.

Comment: Oui, c'est pour ça. Les n-grammes de google n'auront pas de label je pense :/

Comment: Non - et pour sentiment analysis, je ne crois pas que les n-grams soient indiques. On a peut-etre un jeu de donnees au boulot, je vais regarder. Pas sur que je puisse le partager, si on en a un.

Comment: Si vous pouvez, j'apprécierais beaucoup en tout cas. Merci !